# Is it possible to open a remote mac .app application from a web server?

Tags: macos, shell

I'd like to launch a mac application (.app) directly from a web server from a shell script.
I can launch shell scripts directly from the server using curl:

`curl -s http://myserver/myscript.sh | sh`

I can open a local mac app with open:

```
open /Applications/Myapp.app
```

But if I try and open an app directly from the web server using open, it just tries to open my application in a browser window (the default for open):

```
open http://myserver/myapp.app
```

Can anyone think of a way (with curl or open or anything else!) that I can open an app remotely without having to first download it locally?

Comment: But you aren't launching the shell script directly from the server. `curl` downloads it, but instead of writing it to a file on disk, you pipe the contents directly to `sh`. The same could apply to a `.app` bundle, in theory, if you had a program that could read a byte stream and reconstitute it as an application and run it. No such program exists, that I am aware of.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks.  I think my workaround will be to download the app and then run it locally.